# Using jQuery UI widget Autocomplete, how do I implement instant search in ASP.NET MVC 3 app?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I have a page in my ASP.NET MVC 3 app that contains a table displaying database content and a form, that lets you input a search query for filtering the displayed database content. The input to the form is handled by a jQuery UI Autocomplete widget. I have autocomplete support working in the Autocomplete widget, so that a dropdown menu with suggested search terms appears as I type in it.

However, I would also like for the table (of database content) to be automatically filtered as I enter the search string. How do I go about this? Please keep in mind when answering that the solution has to fit the ASP.NET MVC 3 framework (and that I'm new to web development).

Comment: so do you want it to filter the content visible to the user or return a result from the database?

Comment: @Joakim I want to perform a search in the database, thereby filtering the visible content (in the table). That's what the form is doing now, just not instantly as you type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into [DataTables.net](http://datatables.net/). It does accept filtering and is Jquery compatible. If you don't want to use their built in Filter field UI, you can hide that field and call the [fnFilter](http://datatables.net/api) javascript method.

Comment: It looks like it'll only allow filtering on one column, I might want to support several. Also, does it have autocompletion for search terms and does it support inputting several terms (like the StackOverflow tag box)?

Comment: You can filter on multiple columns. There is some discussion about autocomplete on the DataTables.net site (use the google site search function there).

Comment: @Cymen Thanks, looking into it.

Comment: Seems like DataTables is exactly what I need, or it comes very close. Thanks!